# Hide div in Aurelia with Switch statement

Tags: javascript, aurelia

How to hide a div with switch statement. The following is what I am trying to do, but it will hide all divs that is either true or false.

home.html

```
<template>
<div repeat.for="color of colors">
   <div show.bind="condition">
      ${TypeOfGreeting(color)}
   </div>
<div>
</template>
```

home.js

```
export class Home {
condition;
  TypeOfGreeting(color) {
    let text = ""
    switch (color) {
      case "white":
        text = "good morning!";
        condition = true;
        break;
      case "black":
        text = "good night!";
        condition = true;
        break;
      case "orange":
        text = "good evening!";
        condition = true;
        break;
      case "red":
        condition = false;
        break;
      case "blue":
        condition = false;
        break;
      default:
        condition = false;
        text = "Error!";
    }
    return text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`condition` will end up being the value it was set to by the last call to `typeOfGreeting`.

One way to do what you want is to return the `text` and `condition` (`result` in my code) in an object.

See my GistRun: https://gist.run/?id=91735851acd180eab2156e218c213668

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <div repeat.for="color of colors">
     <div show.bind="typeOfGreeting(color).result">
        ${typeOfGreeting(color).text}
     </div>
  <div>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App {
  colors = ['white', 'black', 'orange', 'red', 'blue'];

  typeOfGreeting (color) {
    let result;
    let text = ""

    switch (color) {
      case "white":
        text = "good morning!";
        result = true;
        break;

      case "black":
        text = "good night!";
        result = true;
        break;

      case "orange":
        text = "good evening!";
        result = true;
        break;

      case "red":
        result = false;
        break;

      case "blue":
        result = false;
        break;

      default:
        result = false;
        text = "Error!";
    }

    return {text, result};
  }
}
```